# AutoIT in Selenium File upload locator cannot found

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

```js
public class AutoITDemo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         test();
    }
    
    public static void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        driver.get("https://ps.uci.edu/~franklin/doc/file_upload.html");
        driver.findElement(By.name("userfile")).click();
        
        //calling AutoIT script
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\seleniumTests\\inprogress\\AutoIT\\FileUoloadScript.exe"); 
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

I am trying to go to this URL "https://ps.uci.edu/~franklin/doc/file_upload.html" and upload a file using AutoIT by clicking on the button. But the upload button is not clicked and the following Exception prints on the console. How to solve this?

```js
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.128)
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doVas.png)

Comment: What is the file you are trying to upload? You can do it purely with Selenium by using `sendKeys(absoluteFilePath)` on the element with css selector `input[type='file']`

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
WebElement browse = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='userfile']"));
browse.sendKeys("File path you want to upload");
```